# Simple C program exits prematurely

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a C program ( my first) that asks users for a Char input, and continues running as long as that char's ascii value is not 0. However, my code never seems to reach the while loop part and always exits after the initial printf statement. I made sure it wasn't a problem with the loop by adding a printf statement before the while loop and it still didn't execute.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
 int main(void)
 {
    char c;

    printf("Welcome to ASCII land: "); 
    scanf("%c", &c);

    while((int)'c' != 0) { 
      printf("type in another char "); 
      scanf("%c", &c);
    }   
    printf("you're done");
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Typo? Remove the quotes from `\`c\``

Comment: still have the same problem. I honestly dont think its even reaching that part of code, i duplicated the printf statement and it only outprinted once

Comment: If you just remove the quotes from 'c', you have to type an ASCII 0 to end the loop (not ASCII 48 which is the 0 char)

Comment: You probably need to add an `\n` after `land: ` in `printf("Welcome to ASCII land: ")` (or use `fflush()` or `setbuf(stdout, 0)`. And fix `'c'` to `c`.

Comment: If your intent is to wait for a `0` *value* as `char`, it isn't going to happen with the existing code at all. If you're waiting for a `'0'` *character* as `char`, it will happen, but even then you need to consume the newline entered after the prior input (assuming the user is hitting Enter after each iteration). Regardless, you need to be checking `scanf()` results to ensure one parameter was parsed.

Comment: Why not check the return value of `scanf`?

Comment: On many systems IIRC `scanf` will automatically call `fflush(stdout)` first, but some don't. E.g. see http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=218.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while((int)'c' != 0) {` should probably be `while(c != '0') {`

The original way it is written converts 'c' to a number and compares to 0. 'c' is actually value 99, so you are saying `while (99 != 0)`.

Just removing the quotes from 'c' gives you the questions "how do I enter ASCII 0 (NUL)" ?

Comment: Thank you, but i think that was actually a separate problem. my code doesn't even get to that part of the loop, it simply outputs "welcome to ascii land" and exits when I press enter, without even printing the "youre" don’t part that would otherwise work with or without the loop working

Comment: exits or hangs? Nothing in there should make it exit.

Comment: exits. with the code to your suggested while loop, the output is still      Welcome to ASCII land: e


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue

Comment: so It appeared to be a problem with my editor, I ran it from my terminal and it worked, thanks for the help! I think geany is not compatible with C, is that right?

Comment: Don't know. I don't use it, but you seem to have answered that for yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes in 'c' in the while condition check. You probably are trying to do `while ((int) c != '0'`

Answer (score 0):

I see only problem of **infinite loop** because of `while((int)'c' != 0)`.

This is similar to `while(99 != 0)`. I suggest to modify it to `while(c != '0')`.

Answer (score 0):

`'c'` is a const char, `c` is variable. Pay attention to the difference.
Besides, you cannot input a char whose ascii value is 0. You only can input printable char, such as `'A'`, `'U'`.

Answer (score -1):

1. the condition in while loop is logically incorrect, although it is syntatically correct according to your question. because ascii 0 corresponds to a non-printable character, that you cannot enter from keyboard. so it will run forever
2. sometimes skipping happens . try `scanf(" %c", &c);` in line 7. notice a gap before %c